# camera not responding for opencv videocapture

Tags: python, opencv

I intended to work on opencv as a part of my project.
I want to take images from the webcam and process them. So I used videocapture().
When I used this the camera is not responding for it.
the same program , I tried in both visual studio and jupyter notbook . both resulted the same.
The code is as follows:

```
import cv2 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
key = cv2. waitKey(1)
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)
while True:
    try:
        check, frame = webcam.read()
        print(check) #prints true as long as the webcam is running
        #print(frame) #prints matrix values of each framecd 
        cv2.imshow("Capturing", frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('s'): 
            cv2.imwrite(filename='saved_img.jpg', img=frame)
            webcam.release()
            img_new = cv2.imread('saved_img.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            img_new = cv2.imshow("Captured Image", img_new)
            cv2.waitKey(1650)
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            print("Processing image...")
            img_ = cv2.imread('saved_img.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
            print("Converting RGB image to grayscale...")
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            print("Converted RGB image to grayscale...")
            print("Resizing image to 28x28 scale...")
            img_ = cv2.resize(gray,(28,28))
            print("Resized...")
            img_resized = cv2.imwrite(filename='saved_img-final.jpg', img=img_)
            print("Image saved!")
            plt.show()
            break
        elif key == ord('q'):
            print("Turning off camera.")
            webcam.release()
            print("Camera off.")
            print("Program ended.")
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
        
    except(KeyboardInterrupt):
        print("Turning off camera.")
        webcam.release()
        print("Camera off.")
        print("Program ended.")
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

the

```
print(check)
print(frame)
```

are returning

```
False
None
```

I even tried videocapture(0) and videocapture(-1)
Is problem present in my system or in the code
how to resolve this issue.

Comment: It works on my laptop with ```cv.videoCapture(0)```. Are You sure that You have your camera connected correctly. If You're on laptop maybe there's some issue with accessibility. Try to run the IDE as administrator or something like that.

Comment: always check `assert webcam.isOpened()` right after creating it. if that doesn't even work, all the rest of your code is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Tip 1: you have an excessive amount of code when your sole objective is to test your webcam - see minimized script to check the cam.
Tip 2: shut down or suspend anti virus. I saw several of times anti virus(kaspersky and maybe AVG) blocking python from opening the webcam (I guess to avoid someone hacking your cam).

```py
import cv2


def cam_test(port: int = 0) -> None:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(port)
    if not cap.isOpened():  # Check if the web cam is opened correctly
        print("failed to open cam")
    else:
        print('cam opened on port {}'.format(port))

        for i in range(10 ** 10):
            success, cv_frame = cap.read()
            if not success:
                print('failed to capture frame on iter {}'.format(i))
                break
            cv2.imshow('Input', cv_frame)
            k = cv2.waitKey(1)
            if k == ord('q'):
                break

        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cam_test()
```